# Consuming anonymous type in an Expression

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda

The Entity Framework has a function with this signature:

```
public EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntityType> HasKey<TKey>(Expression<Func<TEntityType, TKey>> keyExpression);
```

If your table has a clustered primary key you can represent that like this:

```
this.HasKey(t => new { t.Field1, t.Field2 });
```

My question is, how are they consuming this anonymous type?  I would like to build some similar functionality in methods of my own, that allow a lambda expression that returns multiple properties.

Is there some special way to peek into an anonymous type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They just use reflection.

For additional performance, you can use expression trees to store pre-compiled delegates in a generic type.

Comment: Guess the obvious answer is the correct one here. Thanks a bunch.